# Mysql rollBack error from different database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, transactions

```
try{
   $SQL=$user_db->prepare("INSERT INTO user (...");
   $SQL->execute();
   $id=$user->lastInsertId('user');//Need this id for next query

   //connect to 2nd db
   //$SQL2=$message_db->prepare("UPDATE....");
}catch{...}
```

I have 2 queries from 2 different db

is any way to roll back the error & stop process if there is any error?

because its from 2 different db so I couldn't use transaction.

ps.1st db is innodb, but **my 2nd db is mysqlISAM** (not support transaction)

Comment: Yes, it is possible for InnoDB. RTFM: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.transactions.php . MyISAM engine, since can not support transactions, can not be rolled back.

Comment: but my 2nd db is in Mysqlisam :(